# Objective-c Cocos2d moving a sprite

Tags: animation, sprites, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d, objective-c

I hope someone knows how to do the following with cocos2d:

I want a sprite to move but not in a single line by using

```
[cocosGuy runAction: [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:location]];
```

What I want is the sprite to do some kind of movements that I preestablish. For example in some point i want the sprirte to move for instance up and then down but in a curve. Do I have to do this with flash like this documents says?

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:animation

Does animation in this page means moving sprites or what?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document you linked to describes approaches to animating sprites. This (usually) doesn't involve the movement of the sprite, but rather an image-sequence that is played in place. Eg. a walk-cycle animation (which will give the impression of a walking character if the sprite is *additionally* moved).

You're on the right track with your approach. Instead of running a single action, you should run a [sequence](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3aactions_composition#sequence) of actions instead. This could be a movement upwards, followed by a [CCBezierTo](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_bezier_to.html) or [CCBezierBy](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_bezier_by.html) action, which allows movement along a Bezier curve.

Using the [CCSequence](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_sequence.html) allows for some pretty complex animations. You can even add [special actions](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3aactions_special) like `CCCallFunc` or similar to execute code at certain points in your sequence.

Comment: Oh, so for example I can first do a move, then enter a function and depending on the sprite's position do one or another move right? Is that possible?

Comment: That's possible. You can run a sequence with: `Move`, `CallFunction`. And then in that function that is being called you could run another action or sequence. There are lots of possibilities with this system.